# Почему если Label достаточно большой, он переносится на новую строку под Radio?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, form, input, checkbox

Всем привет. Не могу понять, почему при верстке HTML страницы на Bootstrap в форме с radio если label большой и выходит за размер блока (делается в 2 строки и более) перепрыгивает на новую строку, и становится как бы под Радио кнопкой, и остается не кликабельное белое поле рядом с кнопкой радио... Подскажите в чем может быть причина, ниже приведен пример моей верстки....

```
... 
 <div class="form-check block_div">
 <input class=" radio" type="radio" name="in1" id="in1" value="1">
       <label class="form-check-label my_controll" for="in1"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</label>
  </div>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

[Читаем](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/strochnye-elementy), видим:

- Ширина равна содержимому плюс значения отступов, полей и границ.
- Несколько строчных элементов идущих подряд располагаются на одной строке и переносятся на другую строку при необходимости.

Выходит, что длинный label переходит на следующую строку и так как занимает всю ширину родительского контейнера + отступы, то текст залезает под радио.

Comment: Это понятно, тут дело в другом, почему label перепрыгивает на новую строку, а дальше идет по обычному правилу переноса (закончилась строка перенес на новую часть строки) отсюда получается пустое пространство рядом с кругляшком input radio, как это поправить?

Comment: Почитайте про строчные и блочные элементы на странице.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за направление... Вроде всё же понятно, но почему то был ступор... решил я это добавив класс во внешний блок, сделав все элементы внутри flex и выровнял их по базовой линии...

```css
.flex-radio{
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check block_div flex-radio">
 <input class=" radio" type="radio" name="in1" id="in1" value="1">
       <label class="form-check-label my_controll" for="in1"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</label>
  </div>
```

Может это и пригодится кому, в частности я уже разобрался почему у меня так криво всё выставлялось... я делал анимацию при наведении, для этого пришлось label задать display: block... в общем добавлением flex стилей всё у меня решилось...

Comment: При смене поведения по умолчанию (строчного на блочное или обратно) можно ждать каких угодно косяков.